# Using OR with two VLOOKUP formulas

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use an OR formula as follows:

```
 =OR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(W1197,Nursery!A:F,6,0),"outofstock"), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(W1197,Annuals!A:G,7,0),"outofstock"))
```

It keeps returning a #VALUE error.

I'm pretty sure I am referencing the correct fields, and I have made this work correctly using only 1 vlookup forumula.  What am I doing wrong with the OR statement?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `OR` expects *logical* expressions that resolve to TRUE/FALSE. Yours resolve to a value or string.... e.g. how would `=OR("foo", "bar")` be interpreted?

Comment: Thank you for that explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(W1197,Nursery!A:F,6,0),VLOOKUP(W1197,Annuals!A:G,7,0)),"outofstock")
```